# System.IO: Convert zip file to byte[] without saving file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, zip, .net-4.5

I'm having trouble using the System.IO.Compression library to create a zip file and then return the byte[] for that zip file. So I want the method to take an input string--the path for the file to be zipped--and return the corresponding byte array for the file once it's been zipped. Currently, I can save the zip file to some known path and then use System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path) to get the byte[].

But how can I do this if I don't know beforehand where that zip file should end up (if anywhere at all)? My attempt at the solution is below. It doesn't seem to be working because when I try to reconstruct the zip file from the byte array it says that the archive is in an unknown format or damaged. Note: I've been able to do this using the Ionic DotNetZip library; however, I'm trying to do the same with only the use of System.IO libraries.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

```
private static byte[] CreateZipAndFindBytes(string importfile)
{
  byte[] retVal = null;

  using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
  {
    //ZipArchive(Stream, ZipArchiveMode, Boolean) //true means leave stream open
    using (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive archive = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(memStream, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
      archive.CreateEntryFromFile(importfile, "test.zip"); //adds the file to the zip
    }
    retVal = memStream.ToArray();
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`entryName`, the second parameter of `CreateEntryFromFile` is supposed to be *"The name of the entry to create in the zip archive."*  It's not the name of your zip file.

you're zipping the import file, but also renaming it with a `.zip` extension, and I'm assuming that the import file is not actually a zip.

do this instead

```
archive.CreateEntryFromFile(importfile, importfile); //adds the file to the zip
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem.

Comment: Do you know if this can work if the method takes a directory as an input? As far as I can tell, CreateEntryFromFile doesn't work when given a directory instead of a file

Comment: @Porter is there a method named "CreateEntryFromDirectory"?

Comment: @Porter you might need to do it recursively

Comment: The ZipArchive class does not have a CreateEntryFromDirectory method. The ZipFile class has a CreateFromDirectory method, but the ZipFile class is a static class. So that method will take a directory and create a zip file at some known location. This doesn't seem useful for storing a representation of a zipfile dynamically in memory and then obtaining properties of it (e.g., its byte array).